# Barn Roof Overhang Repair / Attaching Purlins

Tags: repair, roof, roofing, building, cover

I have a ~3000sq/ft barn which has overhangs on either side. They are a bit "off the cuff" in their design and I'm working on repairing them. The "purlins" (I think that is what they are called) are rotted due to the nails holding the corrugated roof on having degraded washers. I am going to replace all nails but I need to replace the purlins. My question is regarding how they are attached. Right now the blocking (shown as green in the image) is the only thing holding them in place. I don't mind just replacing the blocking and keeping it the same but I am wondering if I should use something like Simpson hurricane ties instead. I am reusing the roof metal so the purlins have to stay in the same places/orientation when I replace them to match up the holes in the metal roof. I can't tell if hurricane ties would be the best and if I should use the H1 or H2.5 style (pictured).

As far as I can tell the bracing has held the purlins in place for this long and actually seems like it is in fine shape. I'd still probably replace it with new pressure treated lumber but I also like the idea of a metal bracket better. [image: Layout View] [image: H2.5A][image: H1]

Comment: When you say the blocking indicated in green is the only thing keeping the purlins in place does that mean: (a) That the green blocking is attached to both the rafter and the purlin? (b) There is only one of these green blocks on each rafter? (c) The other purlins are not nailed in any way to the rafters? (d) Are you sure that the purlins are not toe nailed into the top edge of the rafters?

Comment: a) Correct, 2-3 nails in to the rafter and 2-3 in to the purlin
b) there are two, sorry if my diagram is confusing. One on either end. 
c) I don't believe so. I do believe that each purlin overlaps the next and those are nailed together

-- Here is an updated diagram with more of the blocking shown. [image](https://share.cleanshot.com/rxQM2qsT)

Comment: Your updated image shows green blocking at just then ends of each rafter in the top view. However in the side view you show blocking at every purlin. Which is it? If it is the latter there is little point in adding metal brackets unless you want to remove all the blocking in lieu of the metal items. If only two green blocks per rafter then I really suggest that you investigate the other purlins - they are most assuredly toe nailed to the tops of the rafters. Still little impetus to install the metal brackets.

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand the comment you made about the "ends" but I believe (even if my diagram is confusing) there is as much blocking as could be installed. I wasn't sure if that was a proper connection method and/or if I should change it. As long as that works I am happy to keep using it, especially since it seems like much of it is in good condition. Thanks!

Comment: I see that I may have misinterpreted your top view drawing. Sorry about that.